# Return N/A as value in a MINIFS function when value in a criteria range is N/A

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, min, excel-2019

I would like for my formula to return N/A in column G when there is an N/A in column C. The following screenshot provides my current formula:`

`=IFERROR(MINIFS(Hoofdtab!$AE$2:AE19883;Hoofdtab!$V$2:V19883;F6;Hoofdtab!$I$2:I19883;">="&$C$2;Hoofdtab!$I$2:I19883;"<="&$D$2;C6;"<>"&N/A);"N/A")`

I am using excel 2019

[image]

If anyone has any idea about how I should change my formula I would be a very happy man.

Comment: Please insert the formula as text and not just part of the photo.

Comment: My apologies:

```=IFERROR(MINIFS(Hoofdtab!$AE$2:AE19883;Hoofdtab!$V$2:V19883;F6;Hoofdtab!$I$2:I19883;">="&$C$2;Hoofdtab!$I$2:I19883;"<="&$D$2;C6;"<>"&N/A);"N/A")```

Comment: `=IF(C6="N/A";C6;yourformula, minus the ;C6;"<>"&N/A)`?

Comment: @BigBen This still returns N/A values for every entry in column G instead of only giving N/A for values that are N/A in column C.

Thanks for the input though!

Comment: @BigBen My mistake! It actually worked, thank you so much!!!!!!